# Navbar is expanded automatically when logged out and logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar is expanded automatically when I logout and login again using bootstrap. But I don't want That to happen. When I login again it should not be expanded. 
When I check my code using f12, whenever I login `aria-expanded = "true"` is automatically being place as a part of code. But there is no such code in actual file. Also when I place `aria-expanded = "false"` it is still taking it as `aria-expanded = "true"` when I logout and login. I dont know what is going wrong and where is the issue.

Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: pleaes create a fiddle for better understaning or you can post more code .

Comment: @ Rohit Azad login and logout functionalities are from backend. So I cant provide fiddle. However I can provide more code. I will edit it. Please check.

Comment: Please someone help me. Any links related to similar problem is also fine

Comment: you can once have a look over this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752210/how-to-use-jquery-how-to-change-the-aria-expanded-false-part-of-a-dom-element

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405765/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-auto-expands-on-mobile-tablet
And as info, with bootstrap you got CSS + JS, so that is where those attributes come from, its bootstrap doing its magic.

Comment: But if I remove attr("aria-expanded","true"); it is not expanding at all

Comment: post the code please

Comment: Please share the html code.